# title rendering accoding to image in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

here is my code and I intended to render some slider data,  if image[0] shows up on the slider , I want to return title [0] . I really wonder what I'm missing.[code-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV9Fu.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome at stackoverflow. Better add your code as formatted text in the question. Also a little bit more will most likely be needed to help you.

Comment: isn't it good solution add an image? @Paflow

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Posting images of code is explicitly mentioned as something you should avoid.

Comment: No. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yup, it is better to add your code as formatted text.

Comment: you guys rock , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simply use `i` instead of `images.i`,

```
<v-responsive v-if="i == '0' ">
  {{ titles[0] }} 
</v-responsive >
```

Comment: @oariik AND +1 the answer.

Comment: @oariik in case you need some info on accepting answer
[accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)